# Understanding syslogd

Tags: linux, shell, syslog

could anyone explain what the following line of code does

```
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
```

and how is it different from

```
test -f /var/run/syslogd.pid && kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid`
```

[I know it should restart syslogd, but is there a difference between the two?  bit of a linux noob, sorry]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `/bin/kill -HUP <PID>` - sends **SIGHUP** signal to process identified by `<PID>` (process identifier). Sending this signal to deamons (or services if you prefer) usually  instructs them to reread (read again) their configuration
2. `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` - reads the `/var/run/syslogd.pid` file (which contains **PID** of the **syslogd** daemon) and prints it to standard output (file descriptor = `0` (zero)). The `2> /dev/null` part of it redirects standard error stream (file descriptor = `2` (two)) to `/dev/null` to discard all error messages that occured while reading `/var/run/syslogd.pid`
3. `test -f /var/run/syslogd.pid` - tests if the file `/var/run/syslogd.pid` exists. If it exists it (usually) means that the daemon (in this case **syslogd**) is up and running.

To summarise:

1. The first command means: send **SIGHUP** to **syslogd** discard all error messages and return true if succeded.
2. The second command means: if the **syslogd** daemon is running send **SIGHUP** to it
3. `/dev/null` is a special device file that discards (ignores) everything that is written to it (like a bottomless well). Sometimes used to discard error messages (like in your case here).

Answer (score 0):

The second command is used to check if the file called `/var/run/syslog.pid` exist , this file stores the PID for the running syslog service, the second part of the command will kill that process